# Hacking & Seucrity : suscribe CMS & framework upgrades

Tags: security, exploit

In my daily life I work on multiple websites : some were developed from scratch, others are running frameworks like Jquery, CMS like Symfony/Wordpress/TYPO3 etc...

On a regular basis I go to the official vendors websites to check if any new version / upgrade is available but it is a time-consuming process.

I there any way to automatize this "monitoring work" ?
Any big exploits database to suscribe to ?

The best would be to receive emails every day with the latest news.
If you have any good deal... please share ;)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know a source where you can get all security information (either you can get all security information for all systems or you need to select which systems you are interested in).

for TYPO3 there is a mailing list where you can get all important information regarding TYPO3: http://lists.typo3.org/cgi-bin/mailman/listinfo/typo3-announce